# Tools / ways to process unstructured medical Text data to CSV

Tags: data-analysis, text-processing, bigdata

```
10/03/2014 16:55  Local Title: TRANSFER OUT NOTE
            Standard Title: TRANSFER SUMMARIZATION NOTE
                 AUTHOR:  D,WARD

                      XYZ MEDICAL INSTITUTE 
                 ABC NAGAR, PQW CITY-101011
 ******************************************************************
                       TRANSFER OUT NOTE
                      *******************          OCT 03, 2014

 UHID:000-01-0202   PATIENT NAME:        NAME , SINGH 
 AGE/SEX:42/FEMALE

 DOA:Sep 30,2014

 DEPARTMENT:GYNAE AND OBSTETRICS  UNIT:II

 TRANSFERRED FROM:D3

 NAME , SINGH       000-01-0202                          DOB: 01/01/1972





TRANSFERRED TO : MCU

DIAGNOSIS:pop- em lscs with male baby nicu B


TREATMENT:
inj.cefazolin 1 gm bd
inj.rantac 1 amp tds
inj.perinorm 1 amp tds
inj.pcm 1 gm tds 
inj.texid 1 gm tds


PATIENT STATUS AT THE TIME OF SHIFTING:
  g.c. fair on iv fluid .. 


NAME , SINGH        000-01-0202                          DOB: 01/01/1972




VITALS AT THE TIME OF SHIFTING:
TEMP:98.6F

HR:88/MIN RR:24/MIN

GCS: E V M 


                   <  THE ABOVE NOTE IS UNSIGNED  >                      
- DRAFT COPY * DRAFT COPY * DRAFT COPY * DRAFT COPY * DRAFT COPY * DRAFT  COPY -

 09/21/2014 23:01  Local Title: MED ONCO IRCH DISCHARGE SUMMARY
            Standard Title: DISCHARGE SUMMARY
                 AUTHOR:  KUMAR,UVW

LOCAL TITLE: MED ONCO IRCH DISCHARGE SUMMARY 
STANDARD TITLE: DISCHARGE SUMMARY 

NAME , SINGH        000-01-0202                          DOB: 01/01/1972




DATE OF NOTE: SEP 21, 2014@22:04     ENTRY DATE: SEP 21, 2014@22:04:42 
   AUTHOR: UVW KUMAR 

REGISTRATION DETAILS
********************
 UHID No:000-01-0202    IRCH No:000222    CR No:111000 
 NAME: NAME        AGE:22 YEAR    GENDER:MALE
 DOA:Sep 2, 2014    DOD:Sep 18, 2014    DURATION OF STAY: days 
 WARD: MRO Ward     BED No:14 
 CONSULTANT INCHARGE:Dr UVW Kumar

 DIAGNOSIS & REASON FOR CURRENT ADMISSION
 ****************************************
 DIAGNOSIS:Acute Promyelocytic leukemia (Intermediate Risk)

 ADMITTED FOR :Chemotherapy
 CASE SUMMARY:NAME Singh presented with complaints of bleeding gums, fever, 

 NAME , SINGH       000-01-0202                          DOB: 01/01/1972




blurring of vision and gum hypertrophy. He diagnosed as APML in PQW 
hospital based on PS, BMA and PML/RARa positive. He started on ATRA and after 
that reffered here. His basline hemorem at PQW Hospital was s/o Hb : 
4.6, TLC: 1580/cu.mm, Platlet: 6000/cu.mm. So he is classified as
intermideate risk APML. After coming here diagnosis reconfirmed, 
daunorubicin    given   60mg/m2 and continoued on ATRA. No features of 
ATRA syndrome noticed during ward stay. His fibrinogen level were > 450 
mg/dl. He remained afebrile and hemodynamically stable and dischared on
stable condition.

PRESENTATION AT CURRENT ADMISSION
*********************************
 VITAL SIGNS:
 TEMP:99 F   RESP:19/min   PULSE:98/min 
 BP:121/78 mm of Hg   SPO2:99% on RA



NAME , SINGH        000-01-0202                          DOB: 01/01/1972




 GENERAL PHYSICAL EXAMINATION: PERFORMANCE STATUS: I
 PALLOR:+   ICTERUS:-   OEDEMA:-   CYANOSIS:-
 STERNAL TENDERNESS:-   CLUBBING:-  GUM HYPERTROPHY:+ 
 LYMPHNODES: -

BIOMETRIC DETAILS: WEIGHT: 45 kg  HEIGHT:166 cms   BSA: 1.4 m2

INVESTIGATIONS AT CURRENT ADMISSSION
************************************
PS (3/9/2014) : N2, L8, E-, M1, B-, Meta-, Myelo-, Blast 89%. Blast and abnormal

 promyelocytes present. F/S/O Acute promyelocytic leukemia.

 BMA (3/9/2014): Cellular BM shows 90% blast and abnormal promyelocyte. F/S/O 
 APML.

 Flow Cytometery (3/9/2014): 87% abnormal promyelocyte, Positive : CD45, CD15, 

NAME , SINGH        000-01-0202                          DOB: 01/01/1972




CD11b, CD13, CD33, CD64, CD9, CD18, cMPO.
Negative for CD2, CD14, CD117, CD19, HLADR, CCD79a, cCD3.

 Day 12 PS (9/9/2014): N78, L20, E-, M2, B-, Meta-, Myelo_ Promyelo Nil, Blast 
Nil. 


 Condition at discharge: 
 VITAL SIGNS:
 TEMP:99 F   RESP:18/min   PULSE:78/min 
 BP:112/74 mm of Hg   SPO2:99% on RA


 Plan At discharge and follow up: As written in OPD card




NAME , SINGH        000-01-0202                          DOB: 01/01/1972






                   <  THE ABOVE NOTE IS UNSIGNED  >                      
 - DRAFT COPY * DRAFT COPY * DRAFT COPY * DRAFT COPY * DRAFT COPY * DRAFT COPY -

 09/21/2014 22:04  Local Title: MED ONCO IRCH DISCHARGE SUMMARY
            Standard Title: DISCHARGE SUMMARY
                 AUTHOR:  UVW,AMIT

 REGISTRATION DETAILS
 ********************
 UHID No:000-01-0202    IRCH No:000222    CR No:111000 
 NAME: NAME , SINGH         AGE:42    GENDER:FEMALE
 DOA:Sep 2, 2014    DOD:Sep 18, 2014    DURATION OF STAY: days 
 WARD: MRO Ward     BED No:14 
 CONSULTANT INCHARGE:Dr Lalit Kumar
 ADDRESS:             , 

 NAME , SINGH       000-01-0202                          DOB: 01/01/1972




 DIAGNOSIS & REASON FOR CURRENT ADMISSION
 ****************************************
 DIAGNOSIS: 
 Acute Promyelocytic leukemia (Intermediate Risk)

 ADMITTED FOR :Chemotherapy
 CASE SUMMARY:NAME Singh presented with complaints of bleeding gums,  
 fever, blurring of vision and gum hypertrophy. He diagnosed as APML in 
 UVW hospital based on PS and PML/RARa positive. He started on ATRA and 
 after that reffered to XYZ hospital

 PRESENTATION AT CURRENT ADMISSION
 *********************************
 VITAL SIGNS:
 TEMP:F   RESP:/min   PULSE:/min 
 BP:/mm of Hg   SPO2:%


 NAME , SINGH       000-01-0202                          DOB: 01/01/1972





 GENERAL PHYSICAL EXAMINATION: PERFORMANCE STATUS: 
 PALLOR:   ICTERUS:    OEDEMA:   CYANOSIS:
 STERNAL TENDERNESS:   CLUBBING:  GUM HYPERTROPHY: 
 LYMPHNODES: 


 SPECIFIC FINDINGS:

 BIOMETRIC DETAILS: WEIGHT:kgS  HEIGHT:cms   BSA: m2 
 INVESTIGATIONS AT CURRENT ADMISSSION
************************************ 


                   <  THE ABOVE NOTE IS UNSIGNED  >                      
 - DRAFT COPY * DRAFT COPY * DRAFT COPY * DRAFT COPY * DRAFT COPY * DRAFT COPY -


  NAME , SINGH          000-01-0202                          DOB: 01/01/1972
```

This is the text content which I need to convert to CSV. This is details  of one patient which came to hospital multiple times. I wanted to extract medical data in different column head[ Age, Sex, UHID,DOA, department,Diagnosis,treatment, patient status, vitals, local title, standard title, case summary, admitted for, General Physical Examination].

As you can see the repetition of "diagnosis" and there will be chances that the column name may differ as well.

File to be processed is of 15GB.

Please suggest the way to solve the issue. I tried with python, openrefine and ctakes tool.

Please give me some light on how to solve this kind of issue. Restriction is that We have to use only open source free tools.

Comment: *> This is details of one patient* --- that doesn't appear to be the case. There is data about a 22-year-old male surnamed Singh in the middle of data about a 42-year-old female likewise surnamed.

Comment: The 42-year-old and 22-year-old are both given the same DOB by the same recurring line `NAME , SINGH [...] 000-01-0202 [...] DOB: 01/01/1972`.

Comment: We are considering only  01/01/1972 as correct date of birth and the age mentioned is not considered. These can be sometimes, say I was registering for a patient and entered my details and patient info was different, so 2 data, one the person who applied and the one after reaching to hospital, the actual one. And again, there are places where people will enter such details based on your look. I have already experienced such scenario few days before. You can consider male / female as well as error while entry.

Comment: Objective is to get the diagnosis data with respect to UHID considering all records are correct. Erroneous data can be discarded or marked as not available.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some of this with gawk.  The multiline fields, like vitals and treatment, may prove tricky to shoehorn into CSV format, but here's a start on the single value fields.

```
function dump() {
    print age "," sex "," uhid "," doa "," dept "," diagnosis
}

BEGIN { onfirst = 1 }
END { dump() }

{
    sub(/^ */, "")
    sub(/UHID No/, "UHID")
}


match($0, /UHID:([^ ]*)/, a) {
    if(onfirst)
        onfirst = 0
    else
        dump()
    uhid = a[1]
}

match($0, /AGE\/SEX:([0-9]*)\/(.*[^ ]) *$/, a) {
    age = a[1]
    sex = a[2]
}

match($0, /DOA:([^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*)/, a) {
    doa = a[1]
}

match($0, /DEPARTMENT:(.*[^ ]) *UNIT/, a) {
    dept = a[1]
}

match($0, /DIAGNOSIS:(.*[^ ]) *$/, a) {
    diagnosis = a[1]
}
```